# visibleRoles missing from API definition

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I have a sample API definition with `visibility: RESTRICTED` and `visibleRoles: role1,role2`. When I use `apictl init SampleAPI --definition` , the visibleRoles field is missing in the generated api.yaml file. Is there an existing defect/issue for that ?

Comment: What is the apictl version?

Comment: It is Version: 3.2.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the **visibleRoles** field is not getting added when generating api.yaml using **apictl init** in APICTL 3.2.1 which is an issue. Thank you very much for informing this. Will look into that.

Can you kindly add **visibleRoles** fields to your generated api.yaml as a workaround and proceed until this is fixed in APICTL 3.2.1? (This is already fixed in APICTL 4.0.0-Alpha2.)

Comment: What is the latest release of apictl ? The latest I can download is 3.2.1 version. Do you know when the 4.0.0 version is scheduled for release?

Comment: APICTL 4.0.0 will be compatible with APIM 4.0.0. Both of these will be released together around the 2nd quarter of 2021.